# Android(AIR/Actionscript) Cant return FB access_token from stageWebView

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, air, access-token

Im simply trying to get my users access token from FB using stageWebView. When i trace the output from the location change/changing events all i get are google/FB urls, none of which have the token.

**Here is my code:**

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();

function onChanging(e:LocationChangeEvent):void {
    trace(e.location);
    e.preventDefault();
    webView.loadURL(e.location);
    webView.stage = null;
}

function onChange(e:LocationChangeEvent):void {
    trace(webView.location);
    if(webView.location.indexOf("http://google.com") == 0 && webView.location.indexOf("access_token")!=-1) {
        trace("?"+webView.location.substring(webView.location.indexOf("access_token"), webView.location.indexOf("&expires_in")));
        webView.stage = null;
    }
}

function connectFb() {
    webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onChanging);
    webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, onChange);

    webView.stage = stage;
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

    webView.loadURL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789012345&redirect_uri=http://google.com&type=user_agent&display=popup")
}
```

**My Codes output:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=164534120383085&redirect_uri=http://google.com&type=user_agent&display=popup
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164534120383085&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&type=user_agent&display=popup
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164534120383085&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&type=user_agent&display=popup
http://google.com/
http://google.com/
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/
```

I tried every tutorial on the net and even bought a book on AS3 facebook dev & still cant figure this out; Any help would be VERY appreciated since this is a fairly important project to me

Answer (score 0):

Use this where you are Updating UI example Loading Profile photo or Name of User

String acc = session.getAccessToken();

```
 Log.e("Access-Token", acc);
```

Best of Luck

Comment: The question was about AS3 using Adobe Air(Flash) for android, thanx though